# Best way to pass image data

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a simple API and need to pass couple a few variable. This part is simple, however I need to pass an image as well and that's where I get stuck. Is there a reliable way to encode an image and submit it with a $_GET?

I've attempted to use base64_encode but it doesn't seem to work well. I think the URL gets too long and breaks. Is there a better way? In general, how do I pass image data if URL won't work?

Comment: In a get?  No there isn't a really easy way.  You've gotta pass it as a POST or a PUT.  Images are just too darn large to put in a GET.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought... thanks.